# Change color of image mapping

Tags: html, css, image, dictionary, mapping

How can i change the color of the mapping selection (area)?
This css: "area { background-color: red; }" does not work.

```
<img id="map1" src="images/bg.png" usemap="#map1" />
    <map name="map1">
        <area shape="poly" onclick="openNav()" shape="poly" coords="902,516,936,496,940,535"/>
    </map>
```

A hover would be nice, but just to reach it and change the background is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

area tags have to have an image associated with it. you cant just set the background-color to it.

You could have a plain image of the colour you want and place it on the href property of the area tag instead.

Comment: How do associate a img with the area tag?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if the below code works:

```
<area shape="poly" onclick="openNav()" class="poly" coords="902,516,936,496,940,535"/>
```

In css , please make the changes:

```
.poly {
      backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Just check if this works. I didn't run the code.

Comment: Did not work. Also, it should be background-color: red;